# Jedis does not delete keys

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have just installed redis' last version on Ubuntu 18.04.3. I have tried out writing values directly with `redis-cli`.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set myket somevalue
```

I am now trying to delete all values from Jedis:

```
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost", 6379);
    Set<String> names=jedis.keys("NAME:*");
    System.out.println("There are " + names.size() +  " keys to delete");
    Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String s = it.next();
        jedis.del(s);
        System.out.println(s + " has been deleted");
    }
```

However, it always says that there are 0 keys right now. When I query it from `redis-cli`directly, it is still there. How can I delete the keys from Jedis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key name is `myket` and your pattern is `NAME:*`. The pattern `NAME:*` doesn't match `myket`. That's why you're finding 0 matching keys.